# Solr: Using IgnoreFieldUpdateProcessorFactory

Tags: solr, updateexception

I want to prevent the /update/extract request from adding new fields to the schema.xml like "media_white_point"...
I tried to add the update processor **IgnoreFieldUpdateProcessorFactory** to the "UpdateRequestProcessorChain" which includes deduplication & signature processors, by writing this:

```
<processor class="solr.IgnoreFieldUpdateProcessorFactory" />
```

And didn't work as it should; since 
[here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_6_0//solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/IgnoreFieldUpdateProcessorFactory.html) they say that

> By default, this processor ignores any field name which does not exist according to the schema

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: If you don't want new fields to be created, you should probably [disable the creation of new fields instead](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/schemaless-mode.html#disabling-automatic-field-guessing)?

Comment: I tried to add this: <str name="update.autoCreateFields">false</str> to the /update/extract request in solr config and didn't work. Knowing that I am using a java application with solrj to connect & request solr.

Comment: It's not a parameter to the update request handler, but a configuration option set through the Config API.

Comment: Is there a way to add it in solrConfig.xml?